# Deploying existing WAR to embedded Jetty

Tags: java, jsp, jetty, embedded-jetty

My intention is to deploy an existing WAR to embedded Jetty 9.4.5.

Unfortunately I get the following error when trying to open a page (JSP):

```
An error occurred at line: [52] in the generated java file: [/tmp/embedded-jetty-jsp/jsp/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/jsp/MainLayout_jsp.java]
Type mismatch: cannot convert from HashSet<?> to Set<String>

An error occurred at line: [52] in the generated java file: [/tmp/embedded-jetty-jsp/jsp/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/jsp/MainLayout_jsp.java]
Cannot instantiate the type HashSet<?>

An error occurred at line: [52] in the generated java file: [/tmp/embedded-jetty-jsp/jsp/org/apache/jsp/WEB_002dINF/jsp/MainLayout_jsp.java]
Syntax error on token "<", ? expected after this token
```

The line in question in Java is as follows:

```
private static final java.util.Set<java.lang.String> _jspx_imports_packages = new java.util.HashSet<>();
```

It seems that Jasper tried to compile the code as Java 1.6 or below so the diamond operator cannot be interpreted (I am having Java 1.8.0_141).

I tried to set the version but no success:

```
ServletHolder holderJsp = new ServletHolder("jsp",JspServlet.class);
holderJsp.setInitOrder(0);
holderJsp.setInitParameter("logVerbosityLevel","DEBUG");
holderJsp.setInitParameter("compilerTargetVM","1.7");
holderJsp.setInitParameter("compilerSourceVM","1.7");
holderJsp.setInitParameter("keepgenerated","true");
webAppContext.addServlet(holderJsp,"*.jsp");
```

The code that starts Jetty is

```
public class JettyRunner {

  private static File getScratchDir() throws IOException {
     File tempDir = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
     File scratchDir = new File(tempDir.toString(), "embedded-jetty-jsp");

     if (!scratchDir.exists()) {
        if (!scratchDir.mkdirs()) {
           throw new IOException("Unable to create scratch directory: " + scratchDir);
        }
     }
     return scratchDir;
  }

  private static List<ContainerInitializer> jspInitializers() {
     JettyJasperInitializer sci = new JettyJasperInitializer();
     ContainerInitializer initializer = new ContainerInitializer(sci, null);
     List<ContainerInitializer> initializers = new ArrayList<ContainerInitializer>();
     initializers.add(initializer);
     return initializers;
  } 


  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Server server = new Server(8080);

     WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
     File warFile = new File("existing.war");
     webAppContext.setWar(warFile.getAbsolutePath());
     webAppContext.setContextPath("/acme");

     webAppContext.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] {
              new AnnotationConfiguration(),
              new WebInfConfiguration(),
              new WebXmlConfiguration(),
              new MetaInfConfiguration(),
              new FragmentConfiguration(),
              new EnvConfiguration(),
              new PlusConfiguration(),
              new JettyWebXmlConfiguration()
     });

     webAppContext.setAttribute("javax.servlet.context.tempdir", getScratchDir());
     webAppContext.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.containerInitializers", jspInitializers());
     webAppContext.setAttribute(InstanceManager.class.getName(), new SimpleInstanceManager());
     webAppContext.addBean(new ServletContainerInitializersStarter(webAppContext), true);

     ServletHolder holderJsp = new ServletHolder("jsp",JspServlet.class);
     holderJsp.setInitOrder(0);
     holderJsp.setInitParameter("logVerbosityLevel","DEBUG");
     holderJsp.setInitParameter("compilerTargetVM","1.7");
     holderJsp.setInitParameter("compilerSourceVM","1.7");
     holderJsp.setInitParameter("keepgenerated","true");
     webAppContext.addServlet(holderJsp,"*.jsp");

     webAppContext.setAttribute("org.eclipse.jetty.server.webapp.ContainerIncludeJarPattern",".*/[^/]*jstl.*\\.jar$");
     org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList classlist = org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.Configuration.ClassList.setServerDefault(server);
     classlist.addAfter("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration");
     classlist.addBefore("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration", "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");

     HashLoginService hashLoginService = new HashLoginService();
     hashLoginService.setName("Test Realm");
     hashLoginService.setConfig("jetty-realm.properties");

     webAppContext.getSecurityHandler().setLoginService(hashLoginService);

     server.setHandler(webAppContext);          

     // Start Jetty
     server.start();
     server.join();
  }
```

}

Any hint would be highly appreciated!
Thanks, V.

--------------------------- UPDATE 1 ---------------------------
I set the `server.setDumpAfterStart(true);` (thanks @JoakimErdfelt for the hint!) and commented out the code where I set the `compilerTargetVM` etc. (so I don't add the JspServlet to webAppContext!) and I can see that

```
|   += org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler483422889==dftMaxIdleSec=1800 - STARTED
|   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler@7c75222b - STARTED
|   |   |   +- org.eclipse.jetty.security.DefaultAuthenticatorFactory@4c203ea1
|   |   |   += org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler@27f674d - STARTED
|   |   |   |   += jsp@19c47==org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet,jsp=null,order=0,inst=true - STARTED
|   |   |   |   |   +- fork=false
|   |   |   |   |   +- compilerSourceVM=1.7
|   |   |   |   |   +- logVerbosityLevel=DEBUG
|   |   |   |   |   +- compilerTargetVM=1.7
|   |   |   |   |   +- scratchdir=/tmp/embedded-jetty-jsp/jsp
|   |   |   |   |   +- xpoweredBy=false
```

So the Java source is set to 1.7 but still the diamond operator cannot be interpreted by the JVM!
Bummer... Any idea?
Thank you very much!

Comment: A server dump might help. Add `server.setDumpAfterStart(true);` before your `server.start()`. Edit your question and add the dump to it please.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I am updating my post!

Comment: The dump shows that you are using the proper `JettyJspServlet`, but your code is using `JspServlet`.  Assumption: Your code isn't running, the configuration is arriving via the default descriptor definition.

Comment: I had hoped you would include the entire dump, so I could see the list of JARs in your webapp (there are old reports of similar issues to yours, and it was due to a bad WAR file that included JARs that cause conflicts with JSP).

Comment: Sorry, I uploaded the log to https://www.protectedtext.com/vikhor_jetty (the password is 'vikhor_jetty'). Also I alter the `new ServletHolder("jsp",JspServlet.class);` to `new ServletHolder("jsp",JettyJspServlet.class);`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WAR has `WEB-INF/lib/` entries that are conflicting with the updated version of JSP.

Remove the following entries from your WAR.

```
WEB-INF/lib/jstl-1.1.2.jar
WEB-INF/lib/standard-1.1.2.jar
```

Those jars should never have been included in your WAR file in the first place.

Those are provided by the JSP Container.

Also, get rid of this ...

```
webAppContext.setConfigurations(new Configuration[] {
          new AnnotationConfiguration(),
          new WebInfConfiguration(),
          new WebXmlConfiguration(),
          new MetaInfConfiguration(),
          new FragmentConfiguration(),
          new EnvConfiguration(),
          new PlusConfiguration(),
          new JettyWebXmlConfiguration()
 });
```

... and add this instead (before you create the `WebAppContext`) ...

```java
    Configuration.ClassList classlist = Configuration.ClassList
            .setServerDefault( server );
    classlist.addAfter(
            "org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.FragmentConfiguration",
            "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration",
            "org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.PlusConfiguration");

    classlist.addBefore("org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.JettyWebXmlConfiguration",
                        "org.eclipse.jetty.annotations.AnnotationConfiguration");
```

As its inappropriate to "set" the entire configuration list, use the modification routines instead.

Example taken from https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.8.v20171121/examples/embedded/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/embedded/LikeJettyXml.java#L186-L195

Comment: Nice one! I could progress I have a different exception now. :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi @JoakimErdfelt, I am afraid I have to reopen this issue as if I remove the jstl and standard JAR files from the WAR (however they are still in the classpath but not in the WAR) then I get the `The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application` . I presume it means that Jetty cannot find the JSTL JAR. So this latest exception occurs earlier than the original one (detailed in the ticket description above).

Comment: That message is because you have other JSTL jars in your `WEB-INF/lib` that we both missed.  Remove those too.